# How to make an abbreviation that expands without pressing space

Tags: vimscript, neovim, autocmd, abbreviations

I am trying to replicate the behavior of beg abbreviation shown on the page https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-1/ with vimscript. That means I want to make it so that when I type "beg" in insert mode at the beginning of the line, it calls a function that i choose.

I tried to make it with `iabbrev`, but it doesn't expand until i hit space, and space is typed after my abbreviation. It also doesn't recognize if it is the beginning of a line.

Another approach I tried is with an auto command. I added to my init.vim the following

```
function SayHello ()
  if (getline('.') =~ "\s*beg$")
    s/^\(\s*\)beg/\1\\begin{}\r\r\\end{}/
  endif
endfunction

autocmd TextChangedI *.tex call SayHello ()
```

This almost works, but for one problem. It doesn't work if the autocomplete popup is active, which is always because of a plugin I use. So the effect of this code is that as i first type beg, there is no effect, but if i backspace one letter and add it again, it works as intended. I tried to remedy it by adding the command

```
autocmd CompleteChanged *.tex call SayHello ()
```

so that it works anyway if there is autocomplete. Unfortunately it doesn't work, because it tries to edit the buffer of the popup. I tried making the function exit the popup to no effect.

How can I make it work like on the site?

Answer (score 2):

In insert mode, you can expand an abbreviation with `C-]`.  See `:help i_CTRL-]`.

There's an example of calling a function from an abbreviation towards the end of `:help abbreviations`.  You might also want `<expr>` (see `:help :map-expression`):

```
iabbrev <expr> beg SayHello()
```

Update: I just looked at the Lecture Notes article; the author uses Ultisnips which uses autocommands rather than abbreviations to implement snippets.  If you look at Ultisnips' code you can see it [uses the `TextChangedP` autocmd to address the popup problem](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/f5ccf0977c611ffd774ca180774959301baaffad/plugin/UltiSnips.vim#L39-L43).